# Procedure to construct a spectral energy distribution and bolometric light curve of supernovae?

Tags: astrophysics, supernova, photometry, light-curve

Can anyone check the logic of this proposed workflow and/or point me in the direction of a guide and example to check my work?

Proposed procedure to construct a spectral energy distribution and bolometric light curve of supernovae:

1. Correct magnitude values for extinction (galactic and host)
2. Convert magnitude to flux
3. Plot flux against wavelength
4. Integrate the SED over the wavelength range as a Planck function

Comment: I don't understand your last point. What do you mean by integrating the SED _as a Planck function_?

Comment: My understanding is that the SED needs to be integrated over the wavelength range to find the bolometric flux. Therefore, it should not be integrated as I said at all...

It should be integrated as FLambda dLambda over all wavelengths?

Comment: Yes, the bolometric flux is $F=\int F_\lambda d\lambda$